# Data.Aeson encoding optional keys

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have the following problem, I have a JSON format with optional keys that I need to generate from my haskell code.

Lets make an example

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data Person = {
    name :: String,
    shoeSize :: Maybe Int,
    favoriteColor :: Maybe String,
    favoriteFood :: Maybe StringC
} deriving (show, eq, generic)

instance ToJSON Person -- Generic instance
```

now, if I try encoding a Person without a shoesize I still get a key "shoeSize" set to null, what is the Aeson way of making keys optional in *encoding*

edit, example of an encode

```
encode $ Person "windwarrior" Nothing "green" Nothing
```

should result in

```
{"name":"windwarrior", "favoriteColor":"green"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `TemplateHaskell` to derive the `ToJSON` instance instead of `Generic`. The TH functions optionally take an [`Options`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html) which has the `omitNothingFields` option.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Template Haskell, e.g. When you are writing out ToJSON instance exclusively?

Comment: Normally you construct objects for `ToJSON` using the `object :: [Pair] -> Value` helper function. You can write a new one `objectNoNulls :: [Pair] -> Value` as `objectNoNulls = object . filter (\(_, v) -> v /= Null)` which, as it says, filters the null values.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `Options` datatype with an `omitNothingFields` field for `Generics` as well so you don't have to use `TemplateHaskell`, however there's currently (`v0.11.2.0`) [a bug](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/387) that makes it generate invalid JSON under certain circumstances, e.g. several record fields. It has been fixed but is in `master`.

You can also handwrite instances if you prefer, for your example:

```
instance ToJSON Person where
    toJSON (Person name shoeSize favoriteColor favoriteFood) = object fields
      where
        consMay attr = maybe id ((:) . (attr .=))
        conss = consMay "shoeSize" shoeSize
              . consMay "favoriteColor" favoriteColor
              . consMay "favoriteFood" favoriteFood
        fields = conss ["name" .= name]
```